# Set long and double value in Android EditText

Tags: android-edittext

I want to get a long or double value from JSON by adapter list and set them to `EditText` in Android. how can I do this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the JSONObject class you can use

```
try {
    long l = object.getLong(key); // throws exception if there's no long at that key 
}
catch(JSONException json) {}
```

or

```
long l = object.optLong(key); // instead of throwing exception returns 0
```

Then do

```
editText.setText("" + l);
```